# do accepted answers count towards topic badges?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

Do accepted answers with 0 votes count as a +1 towards topic badges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Only votes count towards tag badges (which is what I assume you mean by "topic badges").

Comment: yeah thats what i meant.  should accepted answers count?

Comment: Nope. Nonononono